# Make one liner code for list unstacking in Python

Tags: python, list

```
max_depth = [[i]*36 for i in range(1,11)]
max_depth = [j for k in max_depth for j in k]
```

I want to convert the above code in one line.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a nested list with `[i]*36`, add another `for` to retrieve `i` `36` times:

```
[i for i in range(1,11) for _ in range(36)]
```

---

Which would be equivalent to:

```
max_depth = []
for i in range(11):
    for _ in range(36):
        max_depth.append(i)
```

Comment: `[i]*36` is ok, since `i` is an immutable value.

Comment: Yes, but you have to flatten it afterwards, which apparently is the output structure OP wants @chepner

Comment: what's the use  of _ here?

Comment: @Abhaykumar Its just a convention name for when a variable is not used

Comment: okay...your code is perfectly fine but I am not able to understand it

Comment: Does the normal loop help understand? @Abhaykumar

Comment: yeah...I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import chain

max_depth = list(chain.from_iterable([i]*36 for i in range(1,11)))
```

Going one step further with `itertools`,

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

max_depth = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 36) for i in range(1,11)))
```

Answer (score -1):

The most straight forward solution:

```
[j for k in [[i]*36 for i in range(1,11)] for j in k]
```